# CakePHP Search with Radiobuttons and Dropdown?

Tags: php, search, cakephp, filter

I am pretty new to Cake and have been looking for a Search / Filter Plugin.

Specifically, I am looking for something that works with Radiobuttons and Dropdown-Lists.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the http://cakedc.com/eng/downloads/view/cakephp_search_plugin, which will support what you want, in this link you'll find all that you need to use this plugin.